# Issue with getopts and argument containing two '*'

Tags: shell, getopts

My script is interpreted by /bin/sh and uses getopts. When I do :

`$ ./check_files.sh -d /tmp -td -x*a*`

Ma argument for -x is well used (at the end) :

`+ find /tmp/geany_socket.9912fb56 /tmp/gpg-OBxSqk /tmp/log /tmp/ssh-bfbl8kSNDM8o /tmp/systemd-private-0a769fff0c124fed8a42ec56733ade46-systemd-timesyncd.service-09Wbx1 /tmp/. /tmp/.. /tmp/.ICE-unix /tmp/.Test-unix /tmp/.X0-lock /tmp/.X11-unix /tmp/.XIM-unix /tmp/.font-unix /tmp/.xfsm-ICE-BILXKY -prune -type d ! -name *a*`

But if I replace the 'a' with a 'i' :

`$ ./check_files.sh -d /tmp -td -x*i*`

I get this :

`+ find /tmp/geany_socket.9912fb56 /tmp/gpg-OBxSqk /tmp/log /tmp/ssh-bfbl8kSNDM8o /tmp/systemd-private-0a769fff0c124fed8a42ec56733ade46-systemd-timesyncd.service-09Wbx1 /tmp/. /tmp/.. /tmp/.ICE-unix /tmp/.Test-unix /tmp/.X0-lock /tmp/.X11-unix /tmp/.XIM-unix /tmp/.font-unix /tmp/.xfsm-ICE-BILXKY -prune -type d ! -name check_files.sh`

for the unique reason I have a file with a 'i' in its name in my current directory, this name is passed to the find command (instead of the actual argument wich is `*i*`. I tested with some other files…

I don't have this problème with only one '*' in the argument.

I tried to use simple and double quotes but I get the same results.

Somebody to explain me why ?

I use the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env sh` which call dash. I also ran the script with `bash --posix`, I have a different result but still the same problem I described above.

As requested by @kenorb :

```
(x)
    SEARCH_NAME_EXCLUDE="${OPTARG}";
(i)
    SEARCH_NAME_INCLUDE="${OPTARG}";
;;

[…]

find_name_clause() {
    if [ -n "$1" ]
    then
    FIND_NAME_CLAUSE=" -name $1 "
    fi
    if [ "$1" -a "$2" ]
        then
            FIND_NAME_CLAUSE="${FIND_NAME_CLAUSE} -a "
        fi    
        if [ -n "$2" ]
        then
            FIND_NAME_CLAUSE="${FIND_NAME_CLAUSE} ! -name  $2 "
        fi    
}

find_name_clause "${SEARCH_NAME_INCLUDE}" "${SEARCH_NAME_EXCLUDE}"
FIND_CLAUSE="${FIND_TYPE_CLAUSE} ${FIND_NAME_CLAUSE}"

[…]


nb_files() {
    NB_FILES=$(find $1 $2 |wc -l)
}

nb_files "${search} ${FIND_CLAUSE}"
```

Comment: Could you share relevant code of your script, especially find command? Maybe you should run the script as `-x'*a*'`, since the globbing is expanded before your script is ran.

Answer (score 3):

Set `noglob`

```
set -o noglob
```

before

```
./check_files.sh -d /tmp -td -x*a*
```

or  call it like

```
./check_files.sh -d /tmp -td -x\*i\* # -x'*i*' will do the same
```

Comment: It still does the same. Maybe I have to use this construction elsewhere in the script.

Comment: The issue is probably with `FIND_NAME_CLAUSE="${FIND_NAME_CLAUSE} ! -name  $2 "`

Comment: @Stéphane Sjsam's suggestions solve the issue of how to call the script.  The script itself, however, also needs reworking.  See: ["I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: @sjsam : same with `FIND_NAME_CLAUSE=${FIND_NAME_CLAUSE}"! -name  "$2`

Comment: @Stéphane If you read the link that I left, you will see that it is best if you abandon what you are doing and start over using arrays.

Comment: @Stéphane: I back \@john1024's suggestion.

Comment: @John1024 : it doesn’t solve my issue actually… but anyway thank you, I have an indication on what to search for.

Comment: @Stéphane What _"doesn’t solve my issue actually"_?  Be specific.

Comment: @John1024 I realize I'm in the case 1. of the document you pointed. It won't work the way I do… I'll try to figure another way to do it :(

Comment: @John1024 it doesn't tell me how I can pass an argument like `*x*` correctly (to getopts) and concatanate it to another variable later if `x` is part of a filename in my current directory.

Comment: @Stéphane When passing an argument with wildcards to the script, the argument needs to be quoted.  Sjsam's answer discusses.  When you reference the argument inside the script, it needs to be double-quoted.  If you only have access to a POSIX shell, don't try to put the command into a variable: quoting in variables does not work as you would like.  If you can use bash, then do: it features arrays which can be used to store complex commands.

Comment: I have another part in my script where this variable is used : `tag="(R${SEARCH_TYPE}i:'${SEARCH_NAME_INCLUDE}'x:'${SEARCH_NAME_EXCLUDE}')"` and it works well. This confirms your answers…

Comment: My script needs to run unmodified on ksh on some AIX. So cannot use bash. I know I have to completly rethink the logic to achieve my exclusion with this constraints, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it like this :

```
find_name_clause() {
        if [ $(expr length $1) -gt 2 ]
        then
            FIND_NAME_CLAUSE=" -name "$1
        fi
        if [ $(expr length $1) -gt 2 -a $(expr length $2) -gt 2  ]
        then
            FIND_NAME_CLAUSE=${FIND_NAME_CLAUSE}" -a "
        fi    
        if [ $(expr length $2) -gt 2  ]
        then
            FIND_NAME_CLAUSE=${FIND_NAME_CLAUSE}"! -name  "$2
        fi    
}

find_name_clause "'"${SEARCH_NAME_INCLUDE}"'" "'"${SEARCH_NAME_EXCLUDE}"'"
```